# How do i calculate radio input value with all other input type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code...

```
    <div id="estimate">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="range-slider">
          <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
          <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="{{vl}}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="radio" value="10" class="form-control prc">
<input type="radio" value="20" class="form-control prc">
<input type="radio" value="70" class="form-control prc">
        </div>
        <p id="result"></p>
        </div>
        <script>
        estimate();
    
    $('.form-group').on('change','.prc',function(){
          estimate();
    });
    
    function estimate(){
        let totalSum = 0;
        $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
            let inputVal = $(this).val();
            if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
            }
        });
        
        $('#result').html(totalSum);
    }
    
    var rangeSlider = function(){
      var slider = $('.range-slider'),
          range = $('.range-slider__range'),
          value = $('.range-slider__value');
        
      slider.each(function(){
    
        value.each(function(){
          var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
          $(this).html(value);
        });
    
        range.on('input', function(){
          $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
        });
      });
    };
    
    rangeSlider();
        </script>
```

without radio button calculator working fine but as a radio button how do calcualte those radio button value with this same method.. like as dynamic field.. Can't use any static id that I can call them by id.. it has to be called by each item.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving your problem could be to insert an

```
if(this.type=="radio" && !this.checked) return
```

into your `estimate()` function.

```js
estimate1();

$('.form-group').on('change','.prc',estimate1);

function estimate1(){
 $('#result')
   .html($('.form-group .prc').get()
           .reduce((a,c)=>((c.type!="radio" || c.checked) && (a+=+c.value),a), 0 ) )
}
function estimate(){
  let totalSum = 0;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
    if(this.type=="radio" && !this.checked) return
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
        totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }
  });
  
  $('#result').html(totalSum);
}

var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
    range = $('.range-slider__range'),
    value = $('.range-slider__value');
  slider.each(function(){
    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="estimate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="range-slider">
    <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
    <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="{{vl}}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>10<input name="rb" type="radio" value="10" class="form-control prc"></label>
    <label>20<input name="rb" type="radio" value="20" class="form-control prc"></label>
    <label>70<input name="rb" type="radio" value="70" class="form-control prc"></label>
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

And using `Array.prototype.reduce()` you can shorten the `estimate()` function even further, see my version of `estimate1()`.

The unary operator `+` is a further shortcut I used. It will behave less tolerant than the originally used `parseInt()` function. `parseInt()` will parse a string right up to the position of a first non-numeric character while `+` will reject an input string alltogether as soon as there is a single non-numeric character in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do what you want, you need ot check if the input you are currently getting the value for is a `radio` and then also is it is checked.

I have a working demo where I added this into the relevant place in your code.

Remember to add labels to your radios so the user knows their value. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) for correct HTML formatting.

```
// Check if radio button and checked
if ($(this).attr('type') == "radio" && $(this).prop('checked')==false){ 

     // If not change value to 0
     inputVal = 0;
        
}
```

```js
estimate();

$('.form-group').on('change', '.prc', function() {
  estimate();
});

function estimate() {
  let totalSum = 0;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function() {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();

    // Check if radio button and checked
    if ($(this).attr('type') == "radio" &&
      $(this).prop('checked') == false) {

      // If not change value to 0
      inputVal = 0;

    }

    console.log(inputVal);
    if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {
      totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }
  });

  $('#result').html(totalSum);
}

var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
    range = $('.range-slider__range'),
    value = $('.range-slider__value');

  slider.each(function() {

    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function() {
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="estimate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="{{vl}}" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="10" class="form-control prc">
    <input type="radio" value="20" class="form-control prc">
    <input type="radio" value="70" class="form-control prc">
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```